# Regular expression that finds all matches of ${any expression}

Tags: javascript, regex

The following regular expression should find all matches of `${any expression}`, the code is as follows:

```js
const reg= /\$\{[^]+\}/g
let txt= '`${i + " test"} RESULT ${2 + 4} now ${i} hi`'
let result= [...txt.matchAll(reg)];
console.log(result)
```

As you will notice, the result is that it extracts almost the entire string, the correct operation should print in the console an array of 3 elements that would contain the `${any expression}`

The following case shows an error that is generated if I use: `[^}]`

```js
const reg= /\$\{[^}]+\}/g
let i= "some"
let txt= `${i + " test"} RESULT ${2 + 4} now ${i + "}" } hi`
let txtString= '`${i + " test"} RESULT ${2 + 4} now ${i + "}" } hi`'
let result= [...txtString.matchAll(reg)];
console.log(result)
console.log(txt)
```

the expression `${i + "}" }` is valid in JavaScript so the regular expression should return `[${i + "}" }, other matches]` but in the example shown it returns

```
${i + "}
```

Comment: I'm afraid regular expressions aren't powerful enough to parse an arbitrary JavaScript expression.

Comment: If you're trying to implement a JS interpreter, I think regular expression is not the right tool; If however you're trying to do something about a JS [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you can try tag function/tagged template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can describe the token syntax inside `${...}` you can still use a regex, too.

If we assume that

- The match starts with `${`
- The tokens inside may be separated with zero or more whitespaces
- The tokens are separated `+`, `-`, `*` or `/` operators
- The tokens are either strings of word chars (letters, digits, underscores) or double quoted string literals (`"...\"...\\..."`)
- The match ends with `}`

You can then use

```js
const reg= /\${\s*(?:\w+|"[^"\\]*(?:\\[^][^"\\]*)*")(?:\s*[-+\/*]\s*(?:\w+|"[^"\\]*(?:\\[^][^"\\]*)*"))*\s*}/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lBSMpp/1).

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const token = '(?:\\w+|"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\[^][^"\\\\]*)*")';
const op = '[-+/*]';
const reg= new RegExp(String.raw`\${\s*${token}(?:\s*${op}\s*${token})*\s*}`, 'g');
let i= "some"
let txt= `${i + " test"} RESULT ${2 + 4} now ${i + "}" } hi`
let txtString= '`${i + " test"} RESULT ${2 + 4} now ${i + "}" } hi`'
let result= [...txtString.matchAll(reg)];
console.log(result)
console.log(txt)
```